# Call super constructor (closure compiler and library)

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

Using the Google closure compiler and library for inheritance I found two different calls of super constructor in a lot of closure based libraries (forgot where I found it). Not sure if I got it wrong at all.

What is the difference and what is the correct one to use?

```
// Xhrio extends EventTarget
goog.events.EventTarget.call(this);
goog.net.XhrIo.base(this, 'constructor');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either one is fine. I suppose you might say the second one is slightly better because if you later changed `XhrIo` to extend something other than `EventTarget` you might not have to change that line.

You can also use `goog.base(this, 'constructor')` but that is incompatible with strict mode.

Comment: Though after compilation, I believe it *is* compatible with strict mode since the compiler substitutes the base constructor there, without JS hackery. IIRC